# Is executing "ls" from the shell similar to calling os.listdir() from a python script at the kernel level?

Tags: python-3.x, linux-kernel, operating-system, directory-listing, lstlisting

I am looking for a very advanced explanation of what happens when the os.listdir() is called?
A level of explanation similar to [this](https://medium.com/meatandmachines/what-really-happens-when-you-type-ls-l-in-the-shell-a8914950fd73)

I want to understand if typing ls in the shell is equivalent to calling os.listdir() from a script file at the kernel level?

I have referred to the official documentation for os.listdir and many blog posts but none explain it in depth.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by similar. `os.listdir` will use `fdopendir` or `opendir` from POSIX. Presumably the same or equivalent is used by `ls`. You can view the cpython source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/posixmodule.c `_posix_listdir`

Comment: `ls` produces human-readable output text on standard output. `os.listdir()` returns a list to be processed by other parts of the program, but does not output any text on standard output by itself. I'm not sure what you mean by "the kernel level". Do you mean the Python interactive shell?